# Need help with diode circuit

Tags: voltage-clipping

Could someone tell me if I've used the right approach for this problem?

Assuming IDEAL DIODES:

[image]

I am aware this is not a practical application and that it would not work in real life, but I just to follow the right process in analyzing the circuit theoretically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the 10V battery and the diodes D1 and D2 are connected such that both the diodes are forward biased all the time. So this output of this circuit has got no relation with the input of the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBk50zm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As far as output is concerned, the voltage across a short-circuited battery is the output here. Since the diodes are ideal, the battery 'burns out' and output becomes zero volts, in case of non-ideal battery. Talking about ideal case, you can not short circuit an ideal voltage.

Comment: @nidhin: I have trouble understanding your answer: in the first case, D1 *seems* to be reverse-biased at first glance, but if the resulting Vo is 0V, then D1 is forward-biased; this seems to be a contradiction. The same applies to the second case and D2. After all, D1 and D2 seem to be short-circuiting the 10V supply. I assume you are right after all, but where is the flaw in my logic?

Comment: @fmunkert yes you are correct... I didn't notice that.. I will correct it.

Comment: @fmunkert thanks for pointing out the error. Since I can not delete an accepted answer, I have edited the answer.

Comment: @user2802349 I have changed my answer completely. Please go through it.

Comment: Oh OK. But this was given to use to be a simple diode clipper question and I doubt it was supposed to be more complicated than analyzing the output for each half-cycle of the input wave. I suppose the original question had an error.

Comment: @user2802349 The method given in first answer is enough for analysing simple diode clippers. In clipper circuits, the diodes should not be never placed such that both are forward biased at the same time (for any value of inputs). But the circuit in your question is having that condition in all cases of input voltages. That is the error.